# Django - standalone html apps in subdirectory

Tags: python, django

I have django app where i can upload my zipped online catalogue.

File structure is something similar to this:

```
-index.html
-book.swf
-css/
-js/
```

Now I want to store in my media directory in subdirectory named by it's ID.
Example path: `/media/publication/12`

Is there any way to open this directly without rounting? Now i get 403 error.
I could do something like this in some PHP frameworks. I created a subdirectory in my app main directory and I could just open in web browser: `example.com/publication/12` and `index.html` was shown in browser.

I want to do it like this because there is many relative urls in files in these catalogues an when I use routes, relative paths to assets are not working and there is too much css, js and flash files linked in index.html. Regexp replacing isn't working well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Django question; these are all static files and should not go through Django. You need to configure your web server to serve files under `/media/`.

Comment: Sorry but i am newbie in this, and that's not my project but when i log in to admin panel of my hosting I have application type: Django (FastCGI). Is it this what i should look for?

Comment: No. What is your host? You probably need another application type for static files.